# Why my ajaxCollapsiblePanel is not working

Tags: asp.net

I have some problem with my ajaxCollpsiblePanelExtender.When I click on button it should hide the second paragraph.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="_btnCollpasePanel" Text="Click Here to Collapse"/>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: solid 1px #7f9db9; width: 200px;">
            <p>Some collapsible content. Click the button to toggle between 
              showing and hiding the collapsible content.</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="sample">
            <ajax:CollapsiblePanelExtender runat="server" 
             ID="sampleCollapsiblePanel" TargetControlID="sample" 
             CollapseControlID="_btnCollpasePanel"
             ExpandControlID="_btnCollpasePanel" Collapsed="true">
            </ajax:CollapsiblePanelExtender>
            <td style="border: solid 1px #7f9db9; width: 200px;">
                <p>Some collapsible content. Click the button to toggle 
                   between showing and hiding the collapsible content.</p>
            </td>
        </asp:Panel>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the collpasible panel was out side the `<td>` element. It was not working.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="_btnCollpasePanel" Text="Click Here to Collapse"/>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: solid 1px #7f9db9; width: 200px;">
            <p>Some collapsible content. Click the button to toggle between 
              showing and hiding the collapsible content.</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td style="border: solid 1px #7f9db9; width: 200px;">
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="sample">
                <ajax:CollapsiblePanelExtender runat="server" 
                    D="sampleCollapsiblePanel" TargetControlID="sample" 
                    CollapseControlID="_btnCollpasePanel"
                    ExpandControlID="_btnCollpasePanel" Collapsed="true">
                </ajax:CollapsiblePanelExtender>
                <p>Some collapsible content. Click the button to toggle 
                  between showing and hiding the collapsible content.</p>
            </asp:Panel>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```